# UITableView population issue in Swift 3 conversion

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

In previous versions of Swift, I was able to populate the labels on a UITableView from an NSMutableArray of NSMutableDctionary objects. The code which had worked was

```
cell.textLabel?.text = dict.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("KEY") as? String
```

The tooltips do not convert this into a useful alternative, after a few fix it's the result is no longer offering suggestions. Is the issue with the population of the .text value's syntax alone, or have the change to NS objects created a requirement that I use different objects to store my source data as well?

Comment: Use Swift native types. Better use a custom struct or class for the data source. **Never** use `NSMutable...` in Swift if there is a native counterpart. The error occurs because the compiler doesn't know the type of the items in `dict` (which is misleading anyway. It's obviously an array).

Comment: Switching them to an an empty Swift Array and Dictionary object rather than the NS versions did help me get the other section converted. I still need to address errors with the dictionary population but I will ask about those under another topic if need be as it's no longer UITableView related. Thanks.